# Get the size of a file via a cookie using subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, curl, subprocess

I have the following functions

```
def get_files(paths):
    for path in paths:
        file_name = parse_path(path)
        csv_command = "curl -b ./cookie {} > ./tmp/{}".format(path, file_name)
        check_file_size(path)
        subprocess.run([csv_command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    print("success")


def check_file_size(path):
    csv_command = "curl -sI ./cookie {}".format(path)
    subprocess.run([csv_command], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

I currently am able to download and retrieve the files I am looking for from the cookie. Before downloading the file, I would like to check the size of said file and have it be in memory. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way to check the size of the file via the cookie. The fix was setting a buffer limit on the lambda side and when trying to read in the file from the cookie just read in up to a buffer amount, if file goes larger than buffer amount raise an error.